# How to set custom headers in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to set my own custom request header by using **codeigniter framework**.

I am using `$this->input->request_header();` function to see the all requested headers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. What kind of error do you get? Can you provide some code examples?

Answer (score 1):

I think the questioner wants to set his custom header on client side and use it on server side.
Simply set the header in html by some packages like jQuery

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: { "custom_header_name": "myValue" }
});
```

and in server side get it by Codeigniter

```
$this->input->request_headers()['custom_header_name']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `output` class. Note that the `output` class, unlike other classes/libraries is automatically loaded by the system so you do not have to do it.

These are examples of setting different headers (From CodeIgniter's [website](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html)
)

```
$this->output->set_header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
$this->output->set_header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $last_update).' GMT');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: sir it is not set the header in request headers.. I want to send the header to the server side.